# The correct term for $y$ in $y=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, terminology

Given:

$y=f(x)$ than y is:

a) range

b) domain c

c) variable

d) co do-main

I saw this question on an fb page and I couldn't get the right answer. a,b,d cannot be the answers since these are sets. I doubt that c is the correct option but the function is not defined to be variable or constant. I really want to understand what I have missed!

Update: I think c is the most appropriate option but are there more technical reasons to believe that the rest of them are incorrect?

Comment: When we say that a symbol like $y$ is a variable in mathematics, we mean that it represents a value, but we don:'t insist that this value is necessarily changeable or varying.

Comment: @hardmath So is the question rigorous or not? If it is, whats the answer?

Comment: "variable" has no technical meaning in mathematics, unless you're doing formal logic. (c) is the only possible answer, but the question is very poorly phrased.

Comment: @JackM. Can't I just say the question is not complete?

Comment: Sometimes, *independant variable* and *dependant variables* are used for $x$ and $y$, so $(c)$ could be correct. The wording of the question is poor though. Maybe it is a kind of multiple choices question with no correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ certainly is a variable here, which depends on how $f$ is defined, and perhaps also on the "input" value $x$. It can also be said to be a variable because it is unknown.

I think you're "overthinking" the question. The answer here is $c$. In any case, I wouldn't get so bent out of shape about a question on "fb"!

Comment: How can one be so sure that $y$ is variable here? may be y=constant

Comment: It still depends on how $f(x)$ is defined. As it is "unknown", it is a variable.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't get it, how does being **unknown** makes it **variable**?

Comment: Perhaps.... ....

Comment: Are there more technical reasons to believe that a,b,d cannot be the correct options?

Comment: As you say in your post, those options are all sets. $y = f(x)$ is not a set.